# Symfony2 (as php-fpm, behind nginx) not Last-Modified or ETage headers sent?

Tags: symfony, http, nginx, etag, last-modified

```
$response = $this->render("index.html.twig", []);

$response->setPublic();
$response->setVary("Cookie");
$response->setExpires($cache->getExpires());
$response->setLastModified($cache->getLastModified());
$response->setETag($cache->getETag());
```

"Expires" header passed. But not "Last-Modified" or "ETag"

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: disable SSI in nginx configuration